# Is a Daruma doll a good motivation to meditate ?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, motivation

Is using a Daruma doll as a means to motivation to meditate a good idea ?   or is it counter productive ?

Answer (score 1):

They're great but I feel that if you can do it with a Daruma Doll you can do it with any other object.

Anything bright, cosntantly changing or unusual that you're never going to get used to will prompt you to meditate, once you have made that association.

If you're more traditional, set phone wallpapers and/or alarms.